# how to query dataframe using pandas with multiple row conditions?

Tags: pandas

I have the below data set, and I need to use pandas to query the status of build (2979). how many passed and how many failed

```
     build  status
0     2980  passed
1     2979  passed
2     2979  passed
3     2979  failed
4     2978  failed
..     ...     ...
101   2968  failed
102   2968  passed
103   2968  passed
104   2968  passed
105   2968  failed
```

if I do:

```
df_status =df.loc[df['build'] == 2979]
```

it will return the rows of build == 2979. It is what I wanted
but when I do

```
df_status =df.loc[df['build'] == 2979]& df['status']=='passed']
```

it returns `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool].`

How do I fix the problem?

I have tried using :

```
df_status =df.loc[df['build'] == 2979 & df['status']=='passed']
```

and hope to return all row with build ==2979 and status == 'passed', but it return `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). You missed to enclose your expression with some parenthesis.

When you do:

```
df.loc[df['build'] == 2979 & df['status'] == 'passed']
```

Python try to evaluate: `2979 & df['status']` because `&` operator has an higher precedence than `==` operator.

What you should do is:

```
df.loc[(df['build'] == 2979) & (df['status'] == 'passed')]
```

To restore the priority of both operations. The code above is equivalent to:

```
df.loc[df['build'].eq(2979) & df['status'].eq('passed')]
```